# Drag and upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have searched around, found some solutions, but none of them helped me in my case. i have a upload button that works on click, i want it to be able to also drag a file to upload.

HTML:

```
        <div style="margin-top: 0px; width: 45%"  ng-model="files" class="drop-box" onclick="document.getElementById('step-image-upload').click()" ng-disabled="instruction.locked || uploading">
            <p>Drop image files<br/></br/>or click to upload</p>
        </div>
```

javascript + angular:
$

```
scope.fileSelected = function(files)
    {
        var promises = [];
        $scope.uploading = true;

        uploadService.uploadMultiple(files)
        .then(function(images)
        {
            if(!images)
            {
                return $q.reject();
            }

            images.forEach(function(image)
            {
                image.highlightAreas = [];
                promises.push($scope.selected.step.addImage(image)
                .then(function()
                {
                    return $q.resolve(image);
                }));
            });

            return $q.all(promises);
        })
        .then(function(images)
        {
            var promises = [];
            var newImageNumber = $scope.selected.step.images.length;

            images.forEach(function(image, index)
            {
                promises.push(ImageExtension.createLinked({
                    imageNumber: newImageNumber + index,
                    caption: ""
                },
                image)
                .then(function(imageExtension)
                {
                    image.imageExtension = imageExtension;
                    return $q.resolve(true);
                }));
            });

            return $q.all(promises);
        })
        .then(function()
        {
            $scope.uploading = false;
        })
        .catch(function()
        {
            $scope.uploading = false;
            toastService.toastTranslation("CLIENT.EDIT.STEP.UPLOAD_ERROR");
        });

    };
```

obs: i just need to drag it and get the data from it so i can call that a file and use the already done function.

Comment: checkout this link http://wisercoder.com/drag-drop-image-upload-directive-angular-js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, if someone ever needs this, here how i fixed my promblem:
using the module ng-file-upload (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-file-upload)
HTML:

```
<div ngf-drop="dragDrop($file)" ngf-select="fileSelected($files)" ng-model="file" class="drop-box" ngf-drag-over-class="'dragover'" ngf-multiple="true" ngf-allow-dir="true" accept="image/*,application/pdf" ngf-pattern="'image/*,application/pdf'" ngf-drop="upload($file)" style="width:45%; cursor: pointer">
```

in ngf-drop="dragDrop($file)" will trigger the function drag drop whenever a file is dropped in the box.
in ngf-select="fileSelected($files)" on click will trigger a search by your folders to upload a file

Javascript:

```
    $scope.dragDrop = function(file) 
    {
        var files = [
            file
        ];
}
```

and

```
    $scope.fileSelected = function(file)
    {
         var files = [file];
}
```

Hope this will be useful for someone else.